# Symfony2, periodic JS failure with FOS Routing

Tags: javascript, symfony

Sometimes my JS fails to load dynamically via Symfony2, the URLs look like;

> /app_dev.php/js/d5fb045_part_1_main_4.js

Looking at this URL using dev tools shows that the JS is returning;

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method ErrorException::getStatusCode() in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ExceptionHandler.php on line 105

The JS error thrown when this is returned is of course;

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

What is going wrong?

**EDIT**

This does not seem to happen in the prod env. Only in dev.

**EDIT 2**

This is worth showing too [Full Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U39ut.png)

[image]

I am using FOS Routing, it seems to fail and then everything else is canceled. The call to `/app_dev.php/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData` returns nothing, just a blank page with a 500 code.

Although this is not always the case, as here FOS Routing works and then the KnockJS file fails. [Full Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHYXL.png)

[image]

**Edit 3**

This does not seem to happen either when accessing the file directly at

> http://www.example.com/app_dev.php/css/9d6987e_part_1_style_1.css

Its only when it loads from within a page.